# How to trigger pull request merge in Bitbucket from Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket.org, atlassian-crowd

I have to preapre a job in Jenkins which allow to pull request merge in Bitbucket. I couldnt't find any addons on Bitbucket and Jenkins as well. I've made workaround which merging locally these two branches and pulling back to Bitbucket but I affraid using this solution on production.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Bitbucket API to trigger a merge:

https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.16.0/bitbucket-rest.html?utm_source=%2Fstatic%2Frest%2Fbitbucket-server%2Flatest%2Fbitbucket-rest.html&utm_medium=301#idm46229602301248